# Audio and Recording Reuse on iPhone with Monotouch

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin.ios, recording

I just started testing this very simple audio recording application that was built through Monotouch on actual iPhone devices today. I encountered an issue with what seemed to be the re-use of the `AVAudioRecorder` and `AVPlayer` objects after their first use and I am wondering how I might could solve it.

**Basic Overview**

The application consists of the following three sections :

- List of Recordings *(TableViewController)*
- Recording Details *(ViewController)*
- New Recording *(ViewController)*

**Workflow**

When creating a recording, the user would click the "Add" button from the List of Recordings area and the application pushes the New Recording View Controller.

Within the New Recording Controller, the following variables are available:

```
AVAudioRecorder recorder;
AVPlayer player;
```

each are initialized prior to their usage:

```
//Initialized during the ViewDidLoad event
recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(audioPath, audioSettings, out error);
```

and

```
//Initialized in the "Play" event
player = new AVPlayer(audioPath);
```

Each of this work as intended on the initial load of the New Recording Controller area, however any further attempts do not seem to work (*No Audio Playback*)

The Details area also has a playback portion to allow the user to playback any recordings, however, much like the New Recording Controller, playback doesn't function there either.

**Disposal**

They are both disposed as follows (upon exiting / leaving the View) :

```
if(recorder != null)
{
    recorder.Dispose();
    recorder = null;
}

if(player != null)
{
    player.Dispose();
    player = null;
}
```

I have also attempted to remove any observers that could possible keep any of the objects "alive" in hopes that would solve the issue and have ensured they are each instantiated with each display of the New Recording area, however I still receive no audio playback after the initial Recording session.

I would be happy to provide more code if necessary. (*This is using MonoTouch 6.0.6*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I determined that the issue was being caused by the `AudioSession` as both recording and playback were occurring within the same controller.

The two solutions that I determined were as follows:

**Solution 1** *(AudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord)*

```
//A single declaration of this will allow both AVAudioRecorders and AVPlayers
//to perform alongside each other.
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord;

//Upon noticing very quiet playback, I added this second line, which allowed
//playback to come through the main phone speaker
AudioSession.OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker = true;
```

**Solution 2** *(AudioSessionCategory.RecordAudio & AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback)*

```
void YourRecordingMethod()
{
     //This sets the session to record audio explicitly
     AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.RecordAudio;
     MyRecorder.record();  
}

void YourPlaybackMethod()
{
     //This sets the session for playback only
     AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;
     YourAudioPlayer.play();
}
```

For some additional information on usage of the `AudioSession`, visit **[Apple's AudioSession Development Area.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html)**